# Using PassportJS, how does one pass additional form fields to the local authentication strategy?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, callback, passport.js

I'm using passportJS and I'm wanting to supply more than just `req.body.username` and `req.body.password` to my authentication strategy (passport-local).

I have 3 form fields: `username`, `password`, & `foo`

How do I go about accessing `req.body.foo` from my local strategy which looks like:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  {usernameField: 'email'},
    function(email, password, done) {
      User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user' });
        }
        if (password != 1212) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
        }
        console.log('I just wanna see foo! ' + req.body.foo); // this fails!
        return done(null, user, aToken);

      });
    }
));
```

I'm calling this inside my route (not as route middleware) like so:

```
  app.post('/api/auth', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', {session:false}, function(err, user, token_record) {
      if (err) { return next(err) }
      res.json({access_token:token_record.access_token});
   })(req, res, next);

  });
```

Answer (score 197, accepted):

There's a `passReqToCallback` option that you can enable, like so:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  {usernameField: 'email', passReqToCallback: true},
  function(req, email, password, done) {
    // now you can check req.body.foo
  }
));
```

When, set `req` becomes the first argument to the verify callback, and you can inspect it as you wish.

Comment: That works great, thanks. Is `passReqToCallback` in the guide? I didn't see it.

Comment: Not yet.  I'm behind on adding new features/options to the guide.

Comment: This is really helpful for implementing multi-tenant / multi-tenancy authentication, but didn't come up in my google searches.  Hopefully my comment will help folks find this answer in the future.

Comment: This is very helpful. But is it possible to set the `usernameField` according to a condition? I have two options: one is email and the other is phonenumber. and the login table contains these two field along with password.

Comment: Very useful. For anyone wondering, `passReqToCallback` also exists in the `passport-http` module. Based on this, I'd guess it's in many other strategies too.

Comment: Did same but still getting missing credentials error @MathewJohn

Answer (score 1):

In most common cases we need to provide 2 options for login

- with email
- with mobile

Its simple , we can take common filed username and query $or by two options , i posted following snippets,if some one have have same question .

We can also use 'passReqToCallback' is best option too , thanks @Jared Hanson

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username', passReqToCallback: true
}, async (req, username, password, done) => {
    try {
        //find user with email or mobile
        const user = await Users.findOne({ $or: [{ email: username }, { mobile: username }] });

        //if not handle it
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, {
                status: false,
                message: "That e-mail address or mobile doesn't have an associated user account. Are you sure you've registered?"
            });
        }

        //match password
        const isMatch = await user.isValidPassword(password);
        debugger
        if (!isMatch) {
            return done(null, {
                status: false,
                message: "Invalid username and password."
            })
        }

        //otherwise return user
        done(null, {
            status: true,
            data: user
        });
    } catch (error) {
        done(error, {
            status: false,
            message: error
        });
    }
}));
```