# Redirect to register page if user not found in database in passport-facebook node js

Tags: node.js, passport-facebook

I am creating login with facebook using `passport-facebook`.Inside  `function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb){ }` I am checking email(provided by `facebook`) against users table . If user found, I simply set session  but if user is not found in users table, I want to redirect user to register page with data provided by facebook. Can anyone please help me with the same? I followed [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340268/get-request-object-in-passport-strategy-callback)  but not able to use `res.redirect()`, getting **error**

> error err_http_headers_sent cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
// Username does not exist, log error & redirect back
        if (!user){
          console.log('User Not Found with username '+username);
          return done(null, false, 
                res.redirect('/registerationpage'));                 
        }
```

for detail explanation try this post:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619 .

It helps with algorithm and logic also with the examples.

Comment: getting same error after using above code  `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: can you create a code snippet or jsfiddle. because you get such errors with the express.js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client try this then