# Adding additional fields to passport.js local strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

By default, passport.js only accepts username and password in its middleware.

http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/

How do I add a third field? In my case, I need username, email, and password.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784233/using-passportjs-how-does-one-pass-additional-form-fields-to-the-local-authenti

Comment: Duh, thank you, so obvious... :)

Answer (score 22):

Very simple, you just need to add req parameter and set passReqToCallback to true

```
passport.use('loginpassport', new LocalStrategy({
   usernameField: 'uname',
   passwordField: 'upass',
   passReqToCallback: true
   }, function (req, username, password, done) {
        var something = req.body.xxxxx;
   }));
```