# Passport Facebook Authentication Returns Undefined?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, passport-facebook

My facebook strategy is as follows:

```
passport.use(new facebookStrategy({

    clientID: envVars.facebook.clientID,
    clientSecret: envVars.facebook.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: envVars.facebook.callbackURL,
    passReqToCallback : true,
    profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'displayName']
},

function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile); //prints out undefined
}
));
```

And my routes are handled as follows:

```
router.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

router.get('/auth/facebook/redirect', passport.authenticate('facebook'), 
function(req, res){
    res.redirect("/profile");
});
```

What my code manages to do successfully is direct the user to Facebook where they are prompted with a permission to allow my app to access their data. Once accepted my console.log(profile) fires yet it prints out undefined even though the user accepts the permission? I have searched through the documentation and can't seem to figure out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with passReqToCallback. Refer this SO question: [Using PassportJS, how does one pass additional form fields to the local authentication strategy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784233/using-passportjs-how-does-one-pass-additional-form-fields-to-the-local-authenti)

In your case, remove the passReqToCallback:true flag.

```
passport.use(new facebookStrategy({

    clientID: envVars.facebook.clientID,
    clientSecret: envVars.facebook.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: envVars.facebook.callbackURL,
    profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'displayName']
},
```

The other option is to modify your callback and use the first argument, which is the request object.

```
function(req, email, password, done) {
    // now you can check req.body.foo
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you! That's very strange how it seems to remove the data returning.