# How use more than one field in my passport strategy

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, nestjs, passport-local

How I can pass 2 more fiels as username in this scenario? I want to do login by phone_number and SSA not only with email.

```
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
        super({
            usernameField: 'email'
        });
    }
    async validate(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.authenticationService.getAuthenticatedUser(email, password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PassportJS, how does one pass additional form fields to the local authentication strategy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784233/using-passportjs-how-does-one-pass-additional-form-fields-to-the-local-authenti)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the passReqToCallback option to your `super()` call in the constructor, this will provide our validate function with the complete `req` object as the first parameter so we can use it at will like so:

```
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
        super({
            usernameField: 'email',
            passReqToCallback: true
        });
    }
    async validate(req: any, email: string, password: string) {
        // Inspect the req object as you wish
        return this.authenticationService.getAuthenticatedUser(req.body.phone_number, req.body.SSA);
    }
}
```

I took this question as reference, it should work the same for the nestjs/passport library.
[Using PassportJS, how does one pass additional form fields to the local authentication strategy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784233/using-passportjs-how-does-one-pass-additional-form-fields-to-the-local-authenti)

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
        super({
            usernameField: 'phone_number'
        });
    }
    async validate(phone_number: string, password: string) {
        return this.authenticationService.getAuthenticatedUser(phone_number, password);
    }
}
```

I looked for information if new fields could be added, but I did not find anything in the documentation and forums